# Spring WS No adapter for endpoint error

Tags: java, web-services, soapui, spring-ws

I am trying to create a new spring web service in eclipse and test it in soapUI. but when I try to run a request in soapUI it gives me below error.

```
No adapter for endpoint [public org.jdom.Element com.pmp.AdminEndpoint.handleSignInRequest(org.jdom.Element) throws java.lang.Exception]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
```

Below is my `admin.xsd`

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:admin="http://pmp.com/admin/schemas"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="http://pmp.com/admin/schemas">

     <xs:element name="SignInRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Password" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

     <xs:element name="SignInResponse" type="xs:string" />  
</xs:schema>
```

And `spring-ws-servlet.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.pmp"/>
  <sws:annotation-driven/>

  <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="admin"                                                           
    portTypeName="AdminDataService"                                                         
    locationUri="/admin/">                               
  <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/admin.xsd"/>                                                  
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>

<bean id="adminEndpoint" class="com.pmp.AdminEndpoint">
        <constructor-arg ref="adminDataService" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="adminDataService" class="com.pmp.AdminDataServiceImpl" />
    <bean id="adminDataServiceRegister" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
        <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="adminEndpoint" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And the `AdminEndpoint` `handleSignInRequest` method

```
 @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "SignInRequest")    
      @ResponsePayload
      public Element handleSignInRequest(@RequestPayload Element signInRequest)  
          throws Exception {
        String email = emailExpression.valueOf(signInRequest);
        String password = passwordExpression.valueOf(signInRequest);

        adminDataService.signin(email, password);
        return new Element("SignInResponse");
      }
```

Any idea on the problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `com.pmp.AdminDataServiceImpl` anotated with `@Endpoint`?

Comment: it is annotated with `@Service`. the endpoint com.pmp.AdminEndpoint is annotated with `@Endpoint`

Comment: Sorry I copied wrong class name :) I don't see `<sws:annotation-driven/>` in your `spring-ws-servlet.xml` did you specify it?

Comment: Yes, It was there, with that also it gives me the same error.

Comment: sorry can't help you